# HTML Image relative size not stretching as expected in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table, webkit

What is the reason that this image doesn't stretch its height to be as it's width?

**In Webkit only!**

http://jsfiddle.net/CgEhg/8/

Edit: lot of people are having trouble, just use Chrome

Comment: Try only img style defined http://jsfiddle.net/CgEhg/19/ . Not need define other itens. Ok, depende situation is not fine. But expose this. Elements in HTML work diferrent for position and behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best that you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/CgEhg/41/

```
<table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/stgeorge12-hp.png" /></td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
table{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
}    
img{
    height:auto;
     width:100%;
}
td,tr,tbody{
    height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have multiple tables and multiple images for different data to layout, you can define same style for the `table` or `td` with `img` and this should work in `Chrome` as well with `IE` and `Firefox`.

Sample on Fiddle at [**`http://jsfiddle.net/2BdQT/`**](http://jsfiddle.net/2BdQT/)

or

**css**:

```
table, img
{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
}

td,tr,tbody
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

​**html**:

```
<table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/stgeorge12-hp.png"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

​

Comment: This is not good man, I already know that I can set the IMG to 40px. This is not what I need. I want the example to remain exactly as it is because it was specifically created to illustrate a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style `td` of `table` instead of `img` tag

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgEhg/16/)**

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I want.

Comment: You don't understand, I want the image to stretch to 40px automatically as the table size.

Comment: Then the other way is to squish the image to 40px in photoshop. otherwise it will look always bad using css dimensions